# Can python code results be written in Latex?

Tags: python, latex

I am really new in programming, sorry for the awful way of asking.

So for a class of kids I'm helping I am trying to make a program in python which must assign a random integer to 2 variables "A" & "B", once that is done, we must check if the ratio A/B yields an integer.

If that is the case, then we must have python print "A/B=~" so we must print this as a question without displaying the answer.

I achieved this by printing the variables as text once I checked the previously stated condition. So far everything is fine. I did this with a loop 5 times and got 5 different questions. I made it in such a way that changing I couple numbers I can make as many questions as I want.
Just to give an example I got:

```
14/7=
56/8=
35/5=
7/1=
81/3=
```

So the python part was basically done.

What I am unable to do and would appreciate if anyone could help me is the next part.

I have to take this results and and be able to make a pdf, if possible with latex, with the caveat that i don't like the idea of manually typing said results since for all the kids I have to do this around 180 times (30 times per kid). Is there a way to do this, since typing all manually in latex would take forever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generate a latex by Python automatically with pylatex package. Here is a full example about the pylatex: [PyLatex full examples](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/full.html)

I write a small demo if I understand you correctly. These demo will create a latex named "test.tex" in the current directory, and an equation "a/b=0" is printed.

```py
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command,Package, Alignat

doc = Document(default_filepath='basic.tex', documentclass='article')
with doc.create(Subsection('Alignat math environment')):
    with doc.create(Alignat(numbering=False, escape=False)) as agn:
    agn.append(r'\frac{a}{b} &= 0 \\')

# trying to generate the tex and pdf, and do not clean the tex file after generating the pdf
doc.generate_pdf("test", clean_tex=False)
```

If you have tools like latexmk which can convert tex to pdf installed, then a pdf name test.pdf will also created. Otherwise you can use your latex editor open the test.tex file.